# Random Variable can take no values at all?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Is it possible for discrete random variable not to have any value?

ie $P_X(x)=0$?

I think it's not possible because we should get that: $\sum_xP_X(x) =1$. Am I right?

Comment: A random variable is a map $X:\Omega\to E$ from the sample space $\Omega$ of possible outcomes to $E$, the observation space (usually $\Bbb R$). It is a *map*; $X(\Omega)$ cannot possibly be empty, by definition (unless the empty set is a member of $E$, which would just be strange)